# SASS Select Element Only If Sibling Does Not Exists

Tags: css, sass

Sass or CSS select element only if sibling does not exists.  I feel like I am really close, but I keep missing the mark.  I need to have all `<p>` tags red, but if it is the last `<p>` tag && the next element is not a `<ul>` - make it blue.

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/xt0qaL6g/1/
Possible other solution not using not and changing the mentality of the question - https://jsfiddle.net/s06ex4vg/

Example 1:

```
    <p> - red
    <ul>
    <p> - red
    <ul>
    <p> - blue
 ... nothing or anything can be directly after as long as it's not a `<ul>`
```

Example 2:

```
<p> - red
<ul>
<p> - red
<ul>
<p> - red
<ul>
```

```css
p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: red;
}

.text p:last-of-type+ :not(ul) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>Testssssss</p>
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Test 2</p>
  <p>Test3</p>
  <ul>
    <li>item 1-1</li>
    <li>item 2-2</li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    Again
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>asdf</li>
  </ul>

  <p>sadf</p>
  <span>sadf</span>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is no sibling element after the last p tag?

Comment: @AHaworth it to be blue.

Comment: Can you update your stack snippet to include the requested styles? It would make it much easier for us to look at your runnable snippet if the text would reflect what your expectations are.

Comment: I can't think of a use-case for why you would want this. Could it be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? I am curious to see what design you are trying to achieve - perhaps your HTML could be restructured to achieve this more easily?

Comment: @Moob it's really for margin-bottom of 25px on all <p> tags except for the last one, which should be 0 unless a <ul> is right after bc other cases the next elements has margin-top.  I used the red vs. blue to make it more visual for this example.  Maybe I could do if last <p> and next element is a sibling <ul> add margin-top + 25px to the <ul>.  I guess I was seeing if there was some other way with :not to skin the cat that I couldn't think of.

Comment: The other way to do it I guess - https://jsfiddle.net/s06ex4vg/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS :not pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to make the last `p` blue if contains something other than a `ul`

```
.text p:last-of-type:has( + :not(ul)){background-color: blue;}
```

or you could make the last `p` blue by default and set it to red if it *does* contains a `ul`:

```
.text p:last-of-type {background-color: blue;}
.text p:last-of-type:has(+ ul){background-color: red;}
```

At the time of writing [all major browsers support :has](https://caniuse.com/css-has) ***except* for Firefox.**  Here's a CSS solution anyway but you will need a different approach if you want to support Firefox.

```css
p {
  background-color: red;
}

.text p:last-of-type:has( + :not(ul)) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>Para 1</p>
  <ul>
    <li>ul</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Para 2</p>
  <p>Para 3</p>
  <ul>
    <li>ul</li>
  </ul>
  <p>para 4</p>
  <span>not a ul</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to note that :has is not supported on all main browsers as of this moment.

Comment: Noted. I believe Firefox is dragging its heals with this one.

Comment: Right - I would use, but the support of FF is slightly important.

Answer (score 0):

> Have all `<p>` tags red, but if it is the last `<p>` tag & the next element is not a `<ul>` - make it blue.

## `p:last-of-type:not(:has(+ ul))`

Related Stackoverflow question: ["Is there a "previous sibling" selector?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1817792/104380)

```css
p { 
  color: red 
}

p:last-of-type:not(:has(+ ul)) { 
  color: blue 
}
```

```html
<p>Testssssss</p>
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
<p>Test 2</p>
<p>Test3</p>
<ul>
  <li>item 1-1</li>
  <li>item 2-2</li>
</ul>
<p>
  Again
</p>
<ul>
  <li>asdf</li>
</ul>

<p>sadf</p>
<span>sadf</span>
```

##### If you don't want (or can't) use `:has` selector you can write your HTML in reverse and then reverse it back with CSS:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse;
}

p { color: blue; }
ul ~ p { color: red; }
```

```html
<span>sadf</span>
<p>sadf</p>
<ul>
  <li>asdf</li>
</ul>
<p>
  Again
</p>
<ul>
  <li>item 2-2</li>
  <li>item 1-1</li>
</ul>
<p>Test3</p>
<p>Test 2</p>
<ul>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 1</li>
</ul>
<p>Testssssss</p>
```